# Search bar with typing suggestion (Dynamic Placeholder)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking a search bar with dynamic placeholder, similar to https://sentifi.com.

Currently I am using a html bootstrap code to create a simple search bar:

```
          <div class="row">
              <BR></BR>          
              <form action="" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <div class="input-group">
                          <input name="searchtext" value="" class="form-control" type="text" autofocus="autofocus">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-search btn-info" id="addressSearch"> 
                                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                                  <span class="label-icon">Search</span>
                              </button>
                          </span>
                    </div>
              </form> 
            </div>
```

Any help/direction in this regard will be really appreciated.

Comment: Use this http://www.bootply.com/yyP5xsZcrg

Answer (score 0):

> I visited the link you shared in the question and i observe it that
>   you need to use jquery function to write in search bar like that
>   website. You need to save the suggestions in string array and pass
>   them in placeholder one by one with time gap.

Comment: It is better to go with Angular js as it has data binding. And it will reliably fast than jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular js directives for this kind of search bar suggestion.

Create a template like this.

```
<input type='text' ng-model={{serachQuery}} ng-change='getResultSet()'/>
<ul>    
    <li ng-repeat="searchResults in resultSet"> 
</ul>
```

In controller write a function `getResultSet()` then in that function take the search query from the input-box  and make some regex operations to that and bind the object to resultSet.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [jquery ui autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

It will do exactly what you need and can be linked via web service to pull data directly from a database.

```js
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  Start typing a coding language:
  <br/>
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```